# Is it possible to iterate a list with index values in the Widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List` which is a list of image URLs, which I will then use to construct a series of Image widgets as part of a gallery.  The images will be aligned next to each other in a `Wrap`.

I can iterate the list and build my images inside a wrap just fine, but I also need to identify the image index in the `List` and pass it to my image widget

```
var gallery = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg']; // this is sample data, my real data set is much longer and obtained from JSON data

Wrap(
        spacing: 2,
        runSpacing: 2,
        children: [
          for (var image in gallery)
            ImageItem(image: image, index:index) <--- how can I get the index here?
        ],
      )
```

Is it possible to identify the index, or where the image is in my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```dart
var gallery = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg']; // this is sample data, my real data set is much longer and obtained from JSON data

Wrap(
  spacing: 2,
  runSpacing: 2,
  children: [
    for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++)
      ImageItem(image: gallery[i], index: i)
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `mapIndexed` method from the Flutter built-in `collection` package, so your code would be:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // Importing the collection package

var gallery = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg']; // this is sample data, my real data set is much longer and obtained from JSON data

Wrap(
  spacing: 2,
  runSpacing: 2,
  children: gallery.mapIndexed((index,image) => ImageItem(image: image, index: index)).toList(),
)
```